# jquery redirect without losing ajax history

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a small app using php, jquery and ajax where you can, for example to a customer search, have a look at the customer details, and click "back" to take you back to the search page without losing the data. I've included a jquery function in the customer details page to open a new page so that the user can do something. However, when doing this if the user decides to go back the search history is lost and the user is just shown a blank screen.

The user clicks here to open the new page

```
<a onclick="LoadSelectSizecode('<?php echo $custid; ?>')"
   class="ui-btn"
   id="newReservation"
   name="newReservation">
    New Reservation
</a>
```

This function is called:

```
function LoadSelectSizecode(customerid) {
    window.location = "reservation_selectSizecode.php?customerid=" + customerid;
};
```

I thought that this would be the best way to do this as I need to pass the customerid. Does anyone have any suggestions for an alternative that won't clear the search history? Thanks

Comment: Add dynamically invisible `<a href="location here" />` in your dom and then make event click on it. You can find a little bit about the idea here http://porzky.com/2012/09/fake-referrer-with-phantomjs/

Comment: You should use the [Pushstate API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: @estshy I got it the solution was to just use <a href='reservation_selectSizecode.php?customerid=<?php echo $custid; ?>' class='ui-btn' id='newReservation' name='newReservation'>New Reservation</a> .... almost too simple! Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It some type of workaround but it will give you additionally referrer parameter correct.

```
var href = 'http//example.com';
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', href);
document.body.appendChild(link);

// Dispatch Click Event on the link
var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, link);
link.dispatchEvent(evt);
```